# ElasticSearch: Design schema for hieararchy level data?

Tags: elasticsearch

For any object I have data in this format

Title, description, tag

e.g here a mobile, tablet, real estate will have tag heirachy like this

```
Electronics - > Mobile -> Samsung
Electronics - > Mobile -> Nokia
Electronics - > Tablet -> Samsung
RealEstate - > Rent -> Villa
```

Now i want to query like

```
1. find all "mobile" of brand "Samsung" that exist in "Electronics" category
2. find all "Tablet" of brand "Samsung" that exist in "Electronics" category
3. find all "Tablet" of brand "Samsung" that exist in "Electronics" category
3. find all "Villa" for "Rent" that exist in "RealEstate" category
```

How can i design ES schema for this kind of hearahi level data?

Answer (score 1):

This feels like the best case for a flat structure with a number of properties that you can query for.

```
{
  "product": "mobile",
  "brand": "Samsung",
  "category": "Electronics",
  "AnotherProperty": "And so on"
}
```

This very basic approach let's you do all the queries you need.